# Working with Observables and Subjects when doing http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I have a larger angular application where I often need to reach out to my backend. Most of the time my Components ask for the same Object (or ressource). For example I have a ParentComponent with multiple ChildComponents. There I can easily just pass the data I get from my ParentComponent.ts file to the Children via @Input and propterty binding. So far so good. But if I have unrelated components, what is the best practice to make as less requests as possible so that every component gets the object request by the backend? I know I have to use services which I do, but for now a lot of unrelated Components call the same http-method and therefore work wit the same data. This could be prevented by using Subjects I guess, who then .next(data) after I subscribed to it in the Service maybe. But then I dont know which component should make the actual http call. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

just `shareReplay` the data that you got from your server

```
class MyService {
   data$ = http.get('url.with.data').pipe(shareReplay(1));
}

class MyComponent {
...
  data$ = this.myService.data$;
}
```

in this way the result will be lazily asked by the first component that consumes this data and also it will be shared between all the components

Answer (score 0):

all services are singleton, for this reason you can make it:
You need, call to the service, but if the service was called one time in the past, you only get that saved  value, and not call to http again, for get a new value.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class YourService {
   data; //persistent data
   //mybe you can implement some algorithm to check the time, and if I spend more than "x" 
   time, force it to call and not just check if I have valid data
   getData() {
       if (!this.data) {
           http.get('url.com').subscribe((data)=>{
              this.data = data; 
              return data;
           });
       } else {
           return of(this.data); //of return a observable with the existint data
       }
    }
}
```

in each component:

```
 @Component({
  selector:'',
  template:''}
);
export class SomeComponent{

data;

constructor(private yourServices: YourService) { }

    chekData() {
        this.yourServices.getData().subscribe(data=>{
        this.data = data;
        });
    }

}
```